# Are all the royal arms gained through quests?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

So far I'm on chapter 5, and have 4 royal arms, all of which I have found during the course of the main quest. I looked at the display of the royal weapons on the menu and there is a gap between the ones I have found so far.

This led me to believe that I have missed one that I should have found by this point in the story, but I haven't seen a quest for it (optional or main).

I also visited a royal tomb without a related quest, and found only a note from some hunters saying that it had been stolen, which leads me to believe that there will be a quest to retrieve it at some point.

So will I encounter each of the royal arms through the main questline, or can some be found without a related quest?

**Please put any spoilers for beyond Chapter 5 in spoiler tags.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, no you can't expect to find them all through the main quest arc or even through optional side quests:

***MAIN STORY***

- Sword of the Wise - found north of Leide, when accompanied by Cor.
- Blade of the Mystic - found before the fight with Titan.
- Swords of the Wanderer - found behind the waterfall as part of the quest 'The Sword in the Waterfall'.
- Axe of the Conqueror - found in the Keycatrich Trench, Cor leads you here after aquiring the Sword of the Wise.
- Trident of the Oracle - given to you after fighting the deathclaw during the 'Breath of the Glacian' quest.
- Katana of the Warrior - defeat the Marlboro during the 'Hand of the King' quest.
- Sword of the Father - found in Zegnautus Keep.

***Optional***

- Greatsword of the Tall - missing from Tomb of the Tall in Titangrove. You must travel to Costlemark Tower nearby at night and defeat the monster at its innermost sanctum.
- Mace of the Fierce - found at the summit of the Rock of Ravatogh.
- Star of the Rogue - found in the Mrylwood dungeon, near Vesperpool.
- Shield of the Just - found in Thommel's Glade.
- Scepter of the Pious - found in the Malmalam Thicket dungeon
- Bow of the Clever - found in the Balouve Mines dungeon.

Here's a map of the locations:

[image: map of tomb locations]

Comment: OP requested any Royal Arms passed chapter 5 to be in spoiler tags

Comment: @Wondercricket he requested any spoilers past chapter 5 to be tagged so. There isn't any spoilers in this answer however, and technically, we should tag all spoilers before chapter five also.

Comment: I think the spoilers would still apply here because you aren't told anything in-game other than the whereabouts are not fully known. I'd edit this answer to comply with OP request.